# Reverse for 'x' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['grupe/(?P<grupa_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<elev_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I was trying to build a django app which would let me access some groups that contain student(elev) objects. I can't make **Elev** objects show, tho.

**Elevi urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'elevi'

urlpatterns = [
    #/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    #/Grupe/id
    url(r'^grupe/(?P<grupa_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.connect, name="connect"),
    #/Grupe/id/elevi_id
    url(r'^grupe/(?P<grupa_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<elev_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.elev_individual, name="elev_individual")
    ]
```

**Elevi views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Grupa,Elev

def index(request):
    toate_grupele = Grupa.objects.all()
    context = {"toate_grupele" : toate_grupele}
    return render(request,'Elevi/test.html',context)

def connect(request,grupa_id):
    grupa = get_object_or_404(Grupa, pk = grupa_id)
    return render(request,'Elevi/connect.html',{'grupa':grupa})

def elev_individual(request,elev_id):
    elev = get_object_or_404(Elev, pk = elev_id)
    return render(request,'Elevi/elev_individual.html',{'elev':elev})
```

**test.html**

```
{% if toate_grupele %}
<ul>
    {% for grupa in toate_grupele %}
         <li><a href ="{% url 'elevi:connect' grupa.id %}">{{ grupa.nume_grupa }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Nu sunt grupe salvate</p>
{% endif %}
```

**connect.html**

```
<h1>{{ grupa.nume_grupa }}</h1>
<h3>Lista Elevi:</h3>

<ul>
    {% for elev in grupa.elev_set.all %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'elevi:elev_individual' elev.id %}">{{ elev.nume_elev }} {{ elev.prenume_elev }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**elev_individual.html**

```
<p>{{ elev.nume_elev }} {{ elev.prenume_elev }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url pattern doesn't match the view arguments

view

```
def index(request): #url pattern don't need any argument
def connect(request,grupa_id): #url pattern needs one argument
def elev_individual(request,elev_id): #requires one argument
```

url

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'), # good
url(r'^grupe/(?P<grupa_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.connect, name="connect") #good
```

If you look at the error message, `elev_individual` requires two argument in the `def elev_individual(request,elev_id):` view method. To fix this, either remove the second argument so that

```
['grupe/(?P<grupa_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<elev_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

becomes

```
['grupe/(?P<elev_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

or add another argument `elev_id` as the second argument to your view so it becomes

```
def elev_individual(request,grupa_id, elev_id):
```

and filter as necessary

Comment: Hi Sir ,could you help me with this question,I have been troubled for two days:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014809/reverse-for-update-comment-with-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-trie/50015181#50015181