# Reverse for 'update_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment\\/(?P<news_pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm coding a news site.Now I'm detailing with the comment post function.And meet the issue says:

```
Reverse for 'update_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment\\/(?P<news_pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

I have tried many ways and times but still can't solve it and I can't find any wrong with my code.And really need your help.

The comment post function is in the news_detail.html. There are two important apps in my project **news** and **operation** comment models is under **operation**

Here is my **root urls.py**:

```
path('news', include(('news.urls', 'news'), namespace="news")),
path('', include(('operation.urls', 'operation'), namespace="operation")),
```

Here is the **news/urls.py**

```
path('-<int:news_pk>', newsDetailView, name="news_detail")
```

Here is the operation/urls.py:

```
path('comment/<int:news_pk>', views.update_comment, name="update_comment"),
```

Here is the **news/view.py**

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = News.objects.get(id=news_pk)
    title = news.title
    author = news.author_name
    add_time = news.add_time
    content = news.content
    category = news.category
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))

    all_comments = NewsComments.objects.filter(news=news)
    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'title': title,
        'author': author,
        'add_time': add_time,
        'content': content,
        'tags': tags,
        'category': category,
        'all_comments': all_comments,
    })
```

Here is **operation/views.py**

```
def update_comment(request, news_pk):
    news = News.objects.get(id=news_pk)
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and comment_form.is_valid():
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {})
        comments = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("comment")
        news_comment = NewsComments(user=request.user, comments=comments, news=news)
        news_comment.save()

        return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
            'news_comment': news_comment，
            'news'：news
        })
```

And here is the news_detail.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'operation:update_comment' news.pk %}">{% csrf_token %}              

<textarea id="js-pl-textarea" name="comment"></textarea>      

<input type="submit" id="js-pl-submit" value="发表评论"></input></form>
```

Comment: Try settings `news_pk=news.pk` in the `url`.

Comment: try replacing `path('comment/<int:news_pk>', ...)` with `path('comment/<int:pk>', ...)` in operations/urls

Comment: Still not work.

Comment: try `path('^$', include(('operation.urls', 'operation'), namespace="operation")),`

Comment: still not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not passing the `news` object into the context for *news_detail.html*. You can simplify the view a lot by just passing `news` and doing things like `{{ news.title }}` in the template (instead of `{{ title }}`):

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))
    all_comments = NewsComments.objects.filter(news=news)

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'news': news,
        'tags': tags,
        'all_comments': all_comments,
    })
```

Now `news.pk` will work as argument to your `{% url ... %}` tag. I've also ensured a 404 error is generated if the `news` object cannot be found (in your code, it would crash).

Comment: one more question sir,although there is no error warning now and I can open the detail page.But when I post a comment all the comments gone,there comment list in detail page disappeared ,but I can all the comments include the new comment in database.Do you have any idea about the issue?

Comment: That’s because you don’t have `all_comments` in the rendering context in `update_comment` view. So either you add it or instead of `render` you `redirect` to the `newsDetailView` passing in the `news.pk`. I would go for `redirect` (more DRY)

Comment: Done！Really appreciate!

Comment: The last question of today. ;)  I add all_comments in the rendering context in udate_comment.It works.But when I tried to redirect it,it fails.I redirected it like this:    return redirect('newsDetailView', news='news') error says:Reverse for 'newsDetailView' not found. 'newsDetailView' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Could you give me some clue.Thank you so much!!

Comment: You can’t redirect to a view directly you have to use the url constructor. `redirect(reverse('news:news_detail', kwargs={'news_pk': news.pk}))`

Comment: Hi sir,if you don't mind could you could you also help me with this Django ajax form question?Appreciate! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051635/django-ajax-form-submit-wrongly-redirect-to-another-page/50052208?noredirect=1#comment87121524_50052208

Comment: @William you deleted the question while i was answering it.

Comment: Really sorry for that, I have reopened it!I think maybe there are something wrong with my undate_comment url either

Comment: Good morning Sir,very sorry for the deleting!If you would,please still help me with that,I still can't workout!Really appreciate!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051635/django-ajax-form-submit-wrongly-redirect-to-another-page/50052208?noredirect=1#comment87121524_50052208

Comment: Hi sir ,could you please me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145502/django-filter-exclude-foreign-key Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi sir, sorry to trouble you in the weekend, could you give me some advice about this question while you are are free.Hi, could you give me some advice about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278241/choose-which-way-to-calculate-the-pv-and-uv-in-django    Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi friend,could you help with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903751/how-to-merge-same-code-block-in-django Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
{% url 'some-url-name' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

fixed:
Your code is correct. The error hint that:

```
 arguments '('',)' not found. 

 arguments '('',)'
```

Comment: It looks weird，if I use action="{% url 'operation:update_comment' 1 %}",it works.I can opend the detail page without errors.It seems that,I didn't pass the new.id to the template sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

instead of path use `url` il in `urls.py`, it may work.

try like this `url(r'^create_order/(?P<id>\d*)$', views.createOrder, name='create_order')`

Comment: "may", "try". Could you phrase more assertively?